# What location should MongoDB run from on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I am following these instructions to install MongoDB 3.2.5 on Ubuntu 15.10:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/#install-for-64-bit-linux

I am up to step 3:

> Copy the extracted folder to the location from which MongoDB will run.

What location should MongoDB run from?

(Note: I believe this location should be different from where data is stored by defaut ie `/data/db`)

Answer (score 1):

You are free to choose where you want to install MongoDB, but it is customary to install software into `/opt` when not installing software using the package manager (apt in case of Ubuntu).

Why aren't you following the guide for installing on Ubuntu - it's much simpler: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I don't think it applies to 15.10.

Comment: It does apply. Please try. In any case, mongo uses to run in `/usr/bin/mongo` (the binary). Despite @Martin is replying with another question, he is right.

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja answer has been updated with an answer. `/usr/bin`should only be used by the package manager

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja - I followed steps 1 - 4 from the resource suggested (installing 3.2.5) and also ran the lines to "pin" versions.  When I run `sudo service mongod start`, I get message:  `Failed to start mongod.service:  Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Could you run: `whereis mongod` ?

Comment: `mongod: /usr/bin/mongod /etc/mongod.conf /user/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz`

Comment: I beg to differ. `/opt/[<package>|<vendor>]` is for custom software not adhering to FHS otherwise. For software adhering to FHS installed locally without a package manager, `/usr/local` would be more suitable. Though `/opt` is good enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: @user1063287 Could this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617097/mongodb-2-6-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-15-04 ?

Comment: fyi:  i upgraded from Ubuntu `15.10` to `16.04` (something suggested below the post linked to directly above) and then followed mongodb install steps again hoping something would be sorted out, but still get a slightly different error:  `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found`.

Comment: I then tried suggestion of using debian via these steps:  1) removed mongodb-org package and all its dependencies. 2) removed the old mongodb-org-3.2.list created. 3) followed debian install steps from two onwards at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian . Error message is:  `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found`.

Comment: Update:  I decided to just install `mongodb 1:2.6.10-0ubuntu1` from Software Center which contains `2.6.10` versions of mongodb components.  Hopefully it will be updated when MongoDB provides a specific release for 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback!